# Redirect root of subdomain, not the folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Probably a simple .htaccess `RewriteRule` problem but I can't figure it out.

This is the situation:

- `subdomain.domain.com` now has a simple HTML page
- `subdomain.domain.com/folderA`, `subdomain.domain.com/folderB` contains app logic, app data, ...

I'm going to upgrade the simple HTML-page, but in a CMS so it can't stay on that location anymore.

How do I redirect all traffic going to `subdomain.domain.com`(`/index.htm` or any other file here) to `www.domain.com/somepage` **without** rewriting requests to `subdomain.domain.com/folderA` etc or **avoiding** that requests made to any of those files end up at `www.domain.com/folderA/`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in the .htaccess file in the document root of your subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ /somepage [R=302,L]
```

For any URL that does not contain a slash (directory separator) and is not itself a directory then redirect to `/somepage`.

This does assume that you have `DirectoryIndex` set appropriately so that a request for the bare domain is rewritten (which is not handled by the above).

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. (301s are cached.)